# Quadratic Sieve Algorithm: Why is $(x − \lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor)^2 ≡ n ($mod $p)$?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, factoring, sieve-theory

If someone here understands the *Quadratic Sieve Algorithm*, I'm having trouble understanding why every prime $p$ in the factor base needs to a prime such that $n$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$. It is explained on the bottom of page 2 of the paper [found here](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/crab/QFS_Simple.pdf#page=3).

The sentence I'm struggling on is near the bottom of page 2, where it says

> Now if $x$ is in this sieving interval, and if some prime $p$ divides $Q(x)$, then $(x − \lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor)^2 ≡ n ($mod $p)$.

Why is this statement true?

Answer (score 0):

Since 
$Q(x)$
is defined as
$(x+\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor)^2
-n
$,
that follows directly
from this definition.

The comments below show that
I jumped too soon.
However,
looking more closely
at the paper,
I am inclined to agree
with Thomas Andrews
that this is indeed a typo.

I've looked at
$(x+\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor)^2
-(x-\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor)^2
=4x\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor
$,
but this doesn't seem to help.

Comment: How do you get from ($x + \lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor )^2$  to ($x - \lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor )^2$ here?

Comment: Please show me because for some reason I can't see exactly how it does.

Comment: Since the author only appears to use that formula to show thatn $n$ is a quadratic residue, modulo $p$, it would appear that the minus sign in the paper was a typo.

Comment: I found this paper [link](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/crab/QFS_Simple.pdf) and it seems that the it should have been $x + \lfloor \sqrt n \rfloor)^2$